# How to make sure Travis-CI is correctly synced with GitHub repo?

Tags: r, github, travis-ci

I have an R package that I'm testing on travis-ci. I've tried several times to make code corrections based on the job log from the previous build. When I make the appropriate changes and push to the GitHub repo and new build is triggered but ends up halting on the same error.

```
checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘FARSfunctions-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:
> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: fars_summarize_years
> ### Title: Summarize fatality counts by year
> ### Aliases: fars_summarize_years
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> fars_summarize_years(2013)
Warning in value[[3L]](cond) : invalid year: 2013
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `year` is unknown
```

I have many commits hence changed the call to `fars_summarize_years` with the arg `2013` to `2015` and besides putting the example under `\dontrun{}`.

```
#'@examples
#'\dontrun{
#'fars_summarize_years(2015)
#'}
#'@export
#'

fars_summarize_years <- function(years) {
        dat_list <- fars_read_years(years)
        dt <- dplyr::bind_rows(dat_list)
        grpd <- with(dt, dplyr::group_by(dt, year, MONTH))
        sum_stats <- with(grpd, dplyr::summarize(grpd, n = n()))
        results <- with(sum_stats, tidyr::spread(sum_stats, year, n))
        knitr::kable(results, align = 'c', caption = "Fatalities by Month")
}
```

But it still shows up as what the build is using. Why? Shouldn't the push to GitHub resync the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code had been updated in the package /R directory, it was part of the roxygen documentation. When the /man documentation files are created their code is taken from the roxygen docs in the main /R files. **BUT** the /man documentation files are not updated with each change to the roxygen in the /R files. The build on travis.ci was using the /man files to test the examples instead of from the roxygen documentation where there were originally written and saved, and where I was modifying them. The solution was to update the documentation in the /R files and then run `roxygen::roxygenize` which updated the /man files based on the changes made.